# How can I create a curved path for a ball?

Tags: physics

I am creating a soccer game. Now I want to shoot the ball and create an after-effect resulting in a curved path. I tried several things, but nothing seems to work.

I am using a 3D tool, but the camera is from the top. I especially want to create a curve of the ball with the effect to the left or right.

What is the best way to create a effect on the ball?

Comment: 2D or 3D? What are your env tools/apis? What do you already have? Can you edit your question and add more information? Also, if you want parabole, im pretty sure that a simple exponential function can give you the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

The physics are very complicated, so it might be best to fake it by treating it as a weak gravity that pulls left or right depending on the kicker (and each kicker would have their own different fake gravity) and the fake gravity gets stronger as the ball slows down (so the curve becomes more J shaped).  This [sample article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/print/1533) that gives an idea of some of the physics involved. The reason for the complication is that it involves both [turbulent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) and laminar flow (the [equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations) for which are terrible and headache inducing) depending on all sorts of factors such as the roughness of the ball (smooth like a billiard ball, dimpled like a golf ball, and the smoothness of last world cup ball made it move differently from a regular regulation ball), the impulse given to the ball (and how offset from true dead-center it is) and whether the ball is wet or dry.